# Why i get 404 Not Found error when access Slim app deployed on Heroku?

Tags: php, heroku, slim

So, I deployed Slim app on Heroku. Only index route (/) works, for other i get 404 not found error.

This is my routes.php file

```php
    // index
    $app->group('', function(RouteCollectorProxy $group) {
        
        $group->get('/',  EntryPointController::class . ':index' );
        $group->get('/test',  EntryPointController::class . ':test' );
    });

    
    // api
    $app->group('/api/v1', function(RouteCollectorProxy $group) {
        
        $group->get('/products', ProductsController::class . ':all' );
    });
```

Procfile content:

```
web: vendor/bin/heroku-php-apache2 public/
```

For all routes, except index route (/), I get 404 error, although on localhost all works.

So, please, say, how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your root route works, then it sounds like the app deployed fine. Did you upload a `.htaccess` file to explain the rewrite rules to Heroku?  From the [Slim Docs](http://www.slimframework.com/docs/v3/start/web-servers.html#apache-configuration), you need something like:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^ index.php [QSA,L]
```

This lets Apache know to send all requests that aren't to an existing file or directory into your index file (which will route to `routes.php`).